# Bash fails to perform a specific equation inside a script

Tags: bash, equation

I have a simple IRC bot written in Bash. It is using an external CLI IRC client (ii) and just reads the new messages that are sent to the channel from a file, does a little formatting on them, performs a check if they equal to something and in case they do, writes to a file. The stdout of the script is redirected to an "out" file that is read by ii (in case the bot has something to say in the channel).

The main function of the script is to check if the message stored in the `$msg` variable equals to a predefined string. If it does, it calls a function to add a value (points) to a text file with a specific format.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

$points_file="$HOME/points"
$channel="#testchan"

tail -f -n 0 ~/irc/someirc.network.com/$channel/out | \

while read -r time nick msg; do

nick=${nick#"<"}
nick=${nick%">"}

function manage_points () {

    points=$(grep -w $nick $points_file | cut -d% -f2)
    gnu_times=$(grep -w $nick $points_file | cut -d% -f3)
    linux_times=$(grep -w $nick $points_file | cut -d% -f4)

: ${gnu_times:="0"}
: ${linux_times:="0"}

        if [ "$1" -eq 1 ]; then
    new_points=$(($points + $2))
    gnu_times=$(($gnu_times + 1))
        elif [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
            new_points=$(($points-$2))
            linux_times=$(($linux_times+1))
        fi

         if [ ! -z "$points" ]; then
            sed -i "s/.*$nick.*/$nick%$new_points%$gnu_times%$linux_times/" $points_file
               else
                    #baby's first point
                echo "$nick%$new_points%$gnu_times%$linux_times" >> $points_file
            fi
}

if [[ $msg == *"GNU/Linux"* ]] && [[ ! $msg == "!"* ]]; then
    check_last_nick "$nick" || continue

manage_points "1" "1"

elif [[ $msg == *"Linux"* ]] && [[ ! $msg == "!"* ]]; then
    check_last_nick "$nick" || continue
        if [[ $msg == *"Linux kernel"* ]] && [[ ! $msg == "!"* ]]; then

            continue

    fi

manage_points "0" "1"

done > in
```

In this case, the `points` file looks something like this:

```
user1%19%21%2
user2%21%21%0
user3%10%11%1
user4%-3%0%3
```

However, for some reason, the script dies from time to time (not always), with the following error:

```
/home/bot.sh: line 47: 21
21 + 1: syntax error in expression (error token is "21 + 1")
```

Line 47 in the original code is:

```
new_points=$(($points + $2))
```

The weird thing is that it dies every time when it has to perform this exact equation, 21 + 1, i.e. the user has a value of 21 already that is read from the text file and put in the `$points` variable, and we are adding 1 more point.

I have no idea what might be causing this and i have tried various things like playing with spaces (i.e. `$points+$2` instead of `$points + 2`), using various combinations of `expr`, `$(())`, `(())`, etc). There are no weird characters in the `points` file.

Comment: You need to pare this down until the error is isolated. That's the first step in debugging.

Comment: Your indentation hides it well, but there is at least one missing closing `fi`.

Comment: Also, you declare the function `manage_points` in each loop; you should pull it to outside of the loop and make it manipulate function arguments instead of global variables.

Comment: ...and, without seeing the input that triggers the error, it's all but impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables in `new_points=$(($points + $2))` contains [Carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). You need to strip it from the variable before doing arithmetics:

```
strippedPoints=${points//$'\r'}
...
```